# C# string to var data type

Tags: c#, string

How can I change from data type from string to var ?

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        work("checkBox1");
    }

    public void work(string check)
    {

    string number = "1";
            if (number == "1")
            {
                check.Checked = true;
                MessageBox.Show("True");
            }
            else
            {
                check.Checked = false;
                MessageBox.Show("False");
            }

    }
```

How can I solve this problem

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension
>   method 'Checked' accepting

But I want to work button insert checkbox name

Comment: you want to convert from string to var... erm wha!

Comment: There is no `var` data type in c#.  The `var` keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of a local variable, but once the type is inferred, it is fixed.  For example, this doesn't compile: `var x = "Hello"; Console.WriteLine(x); x = 4; Console.WriteLine(x);`  The third statement results in the compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'".

Answer (score 8):

Change..

```
public void work(string check)
```

... to ...

```
public void work(CheckBox check)
```

Then call it like this:

```
work(checkBox1);
```

You *can* work with string and then find the controls via `Form.Controls` but it would be much easier to just work with the CheckBox itself.

---

To address the nitpicking @daveL, you can't have a `var` type as a method parameter.  To make your code work, you could use `CheckBox` or `dynamic`.

To the @daveL's of the world who think this is possible, here's some documentation on [Implicitly Typed *Local* Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

Comment: Beat me to it.  +1.  Good answer.

Comment: I would've provided code for `work` but it really looks like filler code because it makes little sense to me.

Comment: that's great but how do you convert from string to var?

Comment: @daveL:  This is a case of QuestionTitle != QuestionBody.  If you're being sarcastic, I will "whoosh" for you -- _whoosh_.

Comment: Actually it's also in the question body... 7 upticks gah

Comment: @daveL:  I welcome your downvote.

Comment: calm down Shirley.. I haven't down voted you! Laughing too hard

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to pass it the actual reference to the checkbox instead of just the name of the checkbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    work(checkBox1); 
} 

public void work(CheckBox check) 
{ 

string number = "1"; 
        if (number == "1") 
        { 
            check.Checked = true; 
            MessageBox.Show("True"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            check.Checked = false; 
            MessageBox.Show("False"); 
        } 

}
```